# Cannot upgrade my Ubuntu MATE 2104 to 2110 or 2204

Tags: upgrade, 22.04, 21.04, 21.10, ubuntu-mate

When trying to upgrade my dist from 21.04 to 21.10 or 22.04, I receive those error messages in my terminal:

```
1522 upgraded, 48 newly installed, 0 to remove and 42 not upgraded.
212 standard security updates
Need to get 56.0 MB/1,600 MB of archives.
After this operation, 1,127 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Err:1 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 libnss-nisplus i386 1.3-0ubuntu5
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:2 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 libnss-nis i386 3.1-0ubuntu5
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:3 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 libcrypt1 i386 1:4.4.18-4ubuntu1
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:4 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 libnsl2 i386 1.3.0-2build1
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:5 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 libkrb5support0 i386 1.18.3-6
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:6 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 libkrb5-3 i386 1.18.3-6
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:7 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 libgssapi-krb5-2 i386 1.18.3-6
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:8 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 libk5crypto3 i386 1.18.3-6
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:9 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main i386 libkeyutils1 i386 1.6.1-2ubuntu2.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:10 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 gcc-11-base i386 11.2.0-7ubuntu2
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:11 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 libstdc++6 i386 11.2.0-7ubuntu2
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:12 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 libgcc-s1 i386 11.2.0-7ubuntu2
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:13 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 libatomic1 i386 11.2.0-7ubuntu2
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:14 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 libnettle8 i386 3.7.3-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:15 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 libhogweed6 i386 3.7.3-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:16 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 libunistring2 i386 0.9.10-6
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:17 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 libidn2-0 i386 2.3.1-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:18 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 libgnutls30 i386 3.7.1-5ubuntu1
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:19 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 libperl5.32 i386 5.32.1-3ubuntu3
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:20 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 libdb5.3 i386 5.3.28+dfsg1-0.8ubuntu1
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:21 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 libx11-xcb1 i386 2:1.7.2-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:22 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 libx11-6 i386 2:1.7.2-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:23 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 libxdmcp6 i386 1:1.1.3-0ubuntu4
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:24 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main i386 libsystemd0 i386 248.3-1ubuntu8.6
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:25 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main i386 libudev1 i386 248.3-1ubuntu8.6
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:26 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 libavahi-client3 i386 0.8-5ubuntu4
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:27 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 libedit2 i386 3.1-20191231-2build1
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:28 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 libicu67 i386 67.1-7ubuntu1
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:29 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 libavahi-common3 i386 0.8-5ubuntu4
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:30 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 libavahi-common-data i386 0.8-5ubuntu4
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:31 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 libapparmor1 i386 3.0.3-0ubuntu1
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:32 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 libpng16-16 i386 1.6.37-3build4
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:33 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 libdeflate0 i386 1.7-2ubuntu2
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:34 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 libwebp6 i386 0.6.1-2.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:35 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 libzstd1 i386 1.4.8+dfsg-2.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:36 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 libnspr4 i386 2:4.32-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:37 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 libpcre2-8-0 i386 10.37-0ubuntu2
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:38 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 libselinux1 i386 3.1-3build2
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:39 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 libpcap0.8 i386 1.10.0-2build1
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:40 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 libpciaccess0 i386 0.16-1build3
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:41 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 libbrotli1 i386 1.0.9-2build3
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:42 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 librtmp1 i386 2.4+20151223.gitfa8646d.1-2build3
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:43 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 libssh-4 i386 0.9.6-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:44 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 libgcrypt20 i386 1.8.7-5ubuntu2
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:45 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 libgl1 i386 1.3.3-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:46 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 libdrm2 i386 2.4.107-8ubuntu1
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:47 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 libdrm-amdgpu1 i386 2.4.107-8ubuntu1
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:48 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 libdrm-intel1 i386 2.4.107-8ubuntu1
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:49 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 libdrm-nouveau2 i386 2.4.107-8ubuntu1
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:50 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 libdrm-radeon1 i386 2.4.107-8ubuntu1
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:51 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 libdw1 i386 0.185-1build1
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:52 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 libelf1 i386 0.185-1build1
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:53 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 libvulkan1 i386 1.2.162.0-1build1
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:54 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main i386 libgl1-mesa-dri i386 21.2.6-0ubuntu0.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:55 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main i386 libosmesa6 i386 21.2.6-0ubuntu0.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:56 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 libxshmfence1 i386 1.3-1build3
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:57 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main i386 libglx-mesa0 i386 21.2.6-0ubuntu0.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:58 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main i386 libglapi-mesa i386 21.2.6-0ubuntu0.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:59 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main i386 libgbm1 i386 21.2.6-0ubuntu0.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:60 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 libglx0 i386 1.3.3-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:61 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 libglvnd0 i386 1.3.3-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:62 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 liblz4-1 i386 1.9.3-2
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:63 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 libdbus-1-3 i386 1.12.20-2ubuntu2
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:64 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 libwayland-cursor0 i386 1.19.0-2build1
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:65 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 libwayland-egl1 i386 1.19.0-2build1
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:66 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 libxkbcommon0 i386 1.3.0-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:67 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main i386 libasound2 i386 1.2.4-1.1ubuntu3.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:68 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 libogg0 i386 1.3.5-0ubuntu1
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:69 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 libsndfile1 i386 1.0.31-2
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:70 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 libasyncns0 i386 0.8-6build1
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:71 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main i386 libpulse0 i386 1:15.0+dfsg1-1ubuntu2.2
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:72 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 libjack-jackd2-0 i386 1.9.19~dfsg-2ubuntu1
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:73 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 libasound2-plugins i386 1.2.2-2ubuntu1
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:74 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 libgstreamer1.0-0 i386 1.18.5-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:75 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0 i386 1.18.5-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:76 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 libtirpc3 i386 1.3.2-2
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:77 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 libsane1 i386 1.0.32-3ubuntu1
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:78 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe i386 libsane i386 1.0.32-3ubuntu1
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:79 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 libgd3 i386 2.3.0-2ubuntu1
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:80 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 libgphoto2-port12 i386 2.5.27-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:81 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 libgphoto2-6 i386 2.5.27-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:82 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 libieee1284-3 i386 0.2.11-14build1
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:83 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 libpoppler-glib8 i386 21.06.1-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:84 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 libpoppler111 i386 21.06.1-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:85 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main i386 libsnmp40 i386 5.9+dfsg-3ubuntu3.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:86 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 libgpm2 i386 1.20.7-8build1
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:87 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 libcdparanoia0 i386 3.10.2+debian-14build1
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:88 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 libvisual-0.4-0 i386 0.4.0-17build1
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:89 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 gstreamer1.0-plugins-base i386 1.18.5-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:90 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 libmpg123-0 i386 1.28.2-2
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:91 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 libv4l-0 i386 1.20.0-4
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:92 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 libv4lconvert0 i386 1.20.0-4
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:93 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe i386 libroken18-heimdal i386 7.7.0+dfsg-2ubuntu2
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:94 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe i386 libasn1-8-heimdal i386 7.7.0+dfsg-2ubuntu2
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:95 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe i386 libheimbase1-heimdal i386 7.7.0+dfsg-2ubuntu2
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:96 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe i386 libhcrypto4-heimdal i386 7.7.0+dfsg-2ubuntu2
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:97 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe i386 libwind0-heimdal i386 7.7.0+dfsg-2ubuntu2
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:98 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe i386 libhx509-5-heimdal i386 7.7.0+dfsg-2ubuntu2
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:99 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe i386 libkrb5-26-heimdal i386 7.7.0+dfsg-2ubuntu2
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:100 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe i386 libheimntlm0-heimdal i386 7.7.0+dfsg-2ubuntu2
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:101 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe i386 libgssapi3-heimdal i386 7.7.0+dfsg-2ubuntu2
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:102 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 libodbc1 i386 2.3.6-0.1build2
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:103 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe i386 libstb0 i386 0.0~git20200713.b42009b+ds-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:104 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main i386 mesa-vulkan-drivers i386 21.2.6-0ubuntu0.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libn/libnss-nisplus/libnss-nisplus_1.3-0ubuntu5_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libn/libnss-nis/libnss-nis_3.1-0ubuntu5_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libxcrypt/libcrypt1_4.4.18-4ubuntu1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libn/libnsl/libnsl2_1.3.0-2build1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/k/krb5/libkrb5support0_1.18.3-6_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/k/krb5/libkrb5-3_1.18.3-6_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/k/krb5/libgssapi-krb5-2_1.18.3-6_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/k/krb5/libk5crypto3_1.18.3-6_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/k/keyutils/libkeyutils1_1.6.1-2ubuntu2.1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-11/gcc-11-base_11.2.0-7ubuntu2_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-11/libstdc%2b%2b6_11.2.0-7ubuntu2_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libu/libunistring/libunistring2_0.9.10-6_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libi/libidn2/libidn2-0_2.3.1-1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/avahi/libavahi-client3_0.8-5ubuntu4_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libe/libedit/libedit2_3.1-20191231-2build1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apparmor/libapparmor1_3.0.3-0ubuntu1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libp/libpng1.6/libpng16-16_1.6.37-3build4_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libd/libdeflate/libdeflate0_1.7-2ubuntu2_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libw/libwebp/libwebp6_0.6.1-2.1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libz/libzstd/libzstd1_1.4.8%2bdfsg-2.1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/nspr/libnspr4_4.32-1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/pcre2/libpcre2-8-0_10.37-0ubuntu2_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libs/libselinux/libselinux1_3.1-3build2_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libp/libpcap/libpcap0.8_1.10.0-2build1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libp/libpciaccess/libpciaccess0_0.16-1build3_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/b/brotli/libbrotli1_1.0.9-2build3_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/r/rtmpdump/librtmp1_2.4%2b20151223.gitfa8646d.1-2build3_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libs/libssh/libssh-4_0.9.6-1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libg/libgcrypt20/libgcrypt20_1.8.7-5ubuntu2_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libg/libglvnd/libgl1_1.3.3-1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libd/libdrm/libdrm2_2.4.107-8ubuntu1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libd/libdrm/libdrm-amdgpu1_2.4.107-8ubuntu1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libd/libdrm/libdrm-intel1_2.4.107-8ubuntu1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libd/libdrm/libdrm-nouveau2_2.4.107-8ubuntu1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libd/libdrm/libdrm-radeon1_2.4.107-8ubuntu1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/e/elfutils/libdw1_0.185-1build1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/e/elfutils/libelf1_0.185-1build1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/v/vulkan-loader/libvulkan1_1.2.162.0-1build1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mesa/libgl1-mesa-dri_21.2.6-0ubuntu0.1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mesa/libosmesa6_21.2.6-0ubuntu0.1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libxshmfence/libxshmfence1_1.3-1build3_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mesa/libglx-mesa0_21.2.6-0ubuntu0.1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mesa/libglapi-mesa_21.2.6-0ubuntu0.1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mesa/libgbm1_21.2.6-0ubuntu0.1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libg/libglvnd/libglx0_1.3.3-1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libg/libglvnd/libglvnd0_1.3.3-1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/lz4/liblz4-1_1.9.3-2_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dbus/libdbus-1-3_1.12.20-2ubuntu2_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/w/wayland/libwayland-cursor0_1.19.0-2build1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/w/wayland/libwayland-egl1_1.19.0-2build1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libxkbcommon/libxkbcommon0_1.3.0-1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/alsa-lib/libasound2_1.2.4-1.1ubuntu3.1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libo/libogg/libogg0_1.3.5-0ubuntu1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libs/libsndfile/libsndfile1_1.0.31-2_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/liba/libasyncns/libasyncns0_0.8-6build1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/pulseaudio/libpulse0_15.0%2bdfsg1-1ubuntu2.2_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/j/jackd2/libjack-jackd2-0_1.9.19%7edfsg-2ubuntu1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/alsa-plugins/libasound2-plugins_1.2.2-2ubuntu1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gstreamer1.0/libgstreamer1.0-0_1.18.5-1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gst-plugins-base1.0/libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0_1.18.5-1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libt/libtirpc/libtirpc3_1.3.2-2_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/sane-backends/libsane1_1.0.32-3ubuntu1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/sane-backends/libsane_1.0.32-3ubuntu1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libg/libgd2/libgd3_2.3.0-2ubuntu1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libg/libgphoto2/libgphoto2-port12_2.5.27-1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libg/libgphoto2/libgphoto2-6_2.5.27-1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libi/libieee1284/libieee1284-3_0.2.11-14build1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/poppler/libpoppler-glib8_21.06.1-1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/poppler/libpoppler111_21.06.1-1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/net-snmp/libsnmp40_5.9%2bdfsg-3ubuntu3.1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gpm/libgpm2_1.20.7-8build1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/cdparanoia/libcdparanoia0_3.10.2%2bdebian-14build1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libv/libvisual/libvisual-0.4-0_0.4.0-17build1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gst-plugins-base1.0/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base_1.18.5-1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mpg123/libmpg123-0_1.28.2-2_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/v/v4l-utils/libv4l-0_1.20.0-4_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/v/v4l-utils/libv4lconvert0_1.20.0-4_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/h/heimdal/libroken18-heimdal_7.7.0%2bdfsg-2ubuntu2_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/h/heimdal/libasn1-8-heimdal_7.7.0%2bdfsg-2ubuntu2_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/h/heimdal/libheimbase1-heimdal_7.7.0%2bdfsg-2ubuntu2_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/h/heimdal/libhcrypto4-heimdal_7.7.0%2bdfsg-2ubuntu2_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/h/heimdal/libwind0-heimdal_7.7.0%2bdfsg-2ubuntu2_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/h/heimdal/libhx509-5-heimdal_7.7.0%2bdfsg-2ubuntu2_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/h/heimdal/libkrb5-26-heimdal_7.7.0%2bdfsg-2ubuntu2_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/h/heimdal/libheimntlm0-heimdal_7.7.0%2bdfsg-2ubuntu2_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/h/heimdal/libgssapi3-heimdal_7.7.0%2bdfsg-2ubuntu2_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/unixodbc/libodbc1_2.3.6-0.1build2_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/libs/libstb/libstb0_0.0%7egit20200713.b42009b%2bds-1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mesa/mesa-vulkan-drivers_21.2.6-0ubuntu0.1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

please help me :)

Comment: this is happening because 21.04 is already end-of-life. You can follow the steps [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/622735/how-do-i-upgrade-an-end-of-life-ubuntu-distribution) to update anyways

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment.
I have already tried that - didn't work for me.

Comment: what does "didn't work" mean? did you remove the `il.` prefix from all sources in sources.list?

Comment: @Esther, I only see *impish* (21.10) in the lines pasted, not *hirsute*.  But if it was my box; I'd select and try another mirror from https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors  instead of your current https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+mirror/mirror.isoc.org.il-archive   I picked one package at random from your list, `libselinux1 | 3.1-3build2      | impish         | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x` and it was available. If a desktop system, you can re-install rather easily without losing datafiles & having *manually installed* auto packages re-installed (from Ubuntu repos)

Comment: It would be simpler to fresh install 22.04

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)